# Use javascript and html to submit a search to an external website and open in a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, search, external, hashtag

I'm new to the community but I look forward to adding value as I grow in my career as a programmer. I'm a little stuck with something and I'm hoping I can get some help.

I'm really close to getting this right but I have one "#" that's throwing me off.  This is the situation...

I have a search box on chrome extension pop-up I'm building that is meant to submit its input to the search of another website.  Lets say for example I enter into my searchbox "help" and press enter.

The url I go to is this:
    https://example.com/search/main.action/search/doAdvancedSearch.action?searchQuery.search=help

The url I need to go to is the exact same thing but right after "main.action" I need a "#". Like this:
https://example.com/search/main.action#/search/doAdvancedSearch.action?searchQuery.search=help

My html code for the form is as follows:

```
<form target="_blank"  action="https://example.com/search/main.action/search/doAdvancedSearch.action" + "?">
<label>Search :
  <input type="search" name="searchQuery.search">
</label>
  <button type= "submit">Search website</button>
</form>
```

My script is as follows:

```
var searchItem = document.getElementById('search').value;
console.log(searchItem);

function website(){
  window.open('https://example.com/home/main.action', '_blank');
  document.getElementById('q').value = searchItem;
  document.getElementById('searchArchived').click();
  var results = document.getElementById('search-results').value;
};

document.getElementById('gotowebsite').addEventListener('return', website);


}
```

I've tried all kinds of things to add the # in the url but I get no luck whatsoever.  Even putting + "#" after main.action gives me unwanted results. Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

And yes I've tried using the other suggestions that were given to similar questions.  They didn't address the # problem. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job:

```js
function redirect() {
  var searchitem = document.getElementById("search");
  window.location.replace("https://example.com/search/main.action#/search/doAdvancedSearch.action?searchQuery.search" + searchitem.value);
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:redirect()">
  <label>Search :
  <input id="search" type="search">
</label>
  <button type="submit">Search website</button>
</form>
```

To open the search page in a new tab:

```js
function redirect() {
  var searchitem = document.getElementById("search");
  var url = "https://example.com/search/main.action#/search/doAdvancedSearch.action?searchQuery.search=" + searchitem.value;
  window.open(url,"");
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:redirect()">
  <label>Search :
  <input id="search" type="search">
</label>
  <button type="submit">Search website</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Wais.  Copying and pasting this didn't work for me but I think I'm understanding what you're doing.  From looking at your approach it seems I was really over complicating things.  Basically you're establishing my search term from the input box as a variable and then adding that variable to the end of my url. In the past, my search term just jumped in where the "#" was but I'm going to work with what you sent until I figure it out.  One thing is that this button should open the search results in a new tab. I added target="_blank" to your form but that didn't work for me yet.  Thanks!

Comment: I edited my question such that the form opens a new page.

Comment: **You the maannnn!!!**  Thanks Wais.  Using your advice I was able to get it to work.  The only thing I changed was removing the "help" at the end of your code. That was an example of the keyword I was searching and not part of the URL itself. 

Since I was launching this page from a chrome extension I'm building,  it didn't work using **window.location.replace**.  Using **window.open** worked like a charm though.